# Counter is not stopping at 0 and clearInterval not stopping either

Tags: javascript

Just learning Javascript and not understanding why this logic does not work.  Appear to using set and clear interval functions correctly but the counter not stopping at 0.  Help me see what I am missing.  Thanks

```
    $("#start").click(function() {
    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
    count *= 1;
    count2 *= 1;

    function timer() {
        $("#start, #m5Time, #m5Break, #a5Time, #a5Break, #title1, #reset, #breakNum").hide();
        $("#session").show();
        $("#session").html("Session Time: ");
        count -= 1;
        if(count === 0){
            buzzer.play();
            clearInterval(counter);
        }
        $("#num").html(count);
```

Comment: What's the original values of `count` and variables? Also there are some missing close-brackets. On SO we prefer complete and compilable code.

Comment: Hello, tried copying in the complete code but to no avail.  The original value of count is a number in the html file this is set to count, via "var count = parseInt($("#num").html());"  As for the missing closing brackets, I just copied over the part that I thought might be the problem but no brackets are missing, at least according to my cloud9 IDE.

Comment: var count = parseInt($("#num").html());
    var count2 = parseInt($("#breakNum").html());
    $("#start").click(function(){
       var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
       count *= 1;
       function timer(){
           $("#start, #m5Time, #m5Break, #a5Time, #a5Break, #title1, #reset, #breakNum").hide();
           $("#session").show();
           $("#session").html("Session Time: ");
           count -= 1;
           if(count === 0){
             buzzer.play();
             clearInterval(counter);
           }
           $("#num").html(count);   
       }
    });

Comment: Is that your fault or StackOverflow's fault? Certainly yours. Askers are supposed to provide a **minimal** complete example. Also information in comments have no values.

Comment: Wasn't aware I was assigning fault

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you. Improve your question (minimal complete verifiable example) if you want people to answer it.